# How to achieve the Fuuu achievement?

Tags: achievements, le-ninja

In the game **Le Ninja** for iOS, there is a Game Center achievement that asks you to "*annoy the Black Ninja*". Problem is, I don't know what they mean by this! How do you annoy the Black Ninja?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just recently found out how to accomplish the achievement by playing around with the game. All you have to do is repeatedly tap the ninja with the gun on the Menu to gain the achievement.